# Are the ubuntu sites down?

Tags: launchpad, canonical

I just logged in toady and wanted to update my software and apparently apt-get update cannot fetch the launchpad repos. When I checked in my browser neither launchpad.net nor ubuntuforums can be accessed.

So my question is simple: are they down or is it just me?

Comment: Same here in Germany launchpad.net, ubuntuforums.org and  ubuntu.com including it's subdomains are unavailable.

Comment: @LiveWireBT Apparently it doesn't affect the main server for me, only the one in Romania. Could it be an Europe-only issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Note**: As of 1100 UTC on August 18, the servers appear to be coming back online.

- The Launchpad/PPA servers and other websites hosted by Canonical are moving to a new data-center, which is causing some outages.

  [image]
- [Launchpad](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/launchpad.net) and [Ubuntu Forums](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ubuntuforums.com) appear to be down for everyone, as of August 18, 2012, 0830 UTC.
- Recent maintenance on Launchpad has often gone beyond the scheduled time, so take any *expected time* announced with a grain of salt.
- Please [check the *Launchpad Status* Twitter feed.](https://twitter.com/launchpadstatus) or their [blog](http://blog.launchpad.net/) for the latest updates.

Comment: Yep. Under maintenance for 4 hours.

Comment: "Please check http://blog.launchpad.net/ for the latest updates" ... when that website is down xD The Twitter feed is useful though

Comment: Yay now it's back! :D